# Linear Search Generics

Tags: java, generics, search

I just got a homework assignment, and it's just creating a linear search algorithm in java. However, I also want to make this code work with any data type like Strings, ints, doubles, etc and different kinds of containers like arrays, hashsets, lists, and collections, so I won't have to waste so a lot of extra lines to overload the method. Here's the current code.

```
public class Search
{
    public int linear (Object[] contents, Object query)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < contents.length; ++index)
        {
            if (query.equals(contents[index]))
            {
                return index;
            }
         }
         return -1;
    }
}
```

However, in my other class, for testing, I have an int array and an int to search for. I get an error that says "The method linear(Object[], Object) in the type Search is not applicable for the arguments (int[], int)"

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Woops I forgot to add the question. Fixed now haha

Comment: Object[] and int[] are not equivalent.

Comment: `int` is not a class, so you can't use `int[]` as an `Object[]`

Comment: Thanks so much! Other than forgetting that int is not a class, is the above code okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

int is not an object, it's a primitive. you may user Integer[]. Better yet, you should use generics.  You may also want to use list instead of array (just a thought): I show both below.

```
import java.util.List;
public class LinearSearch<E>
{
public int linear (E[] contents, E query)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < contents.length; ++index)
    {
        if (query.equals(contents[index]))
        {
            return index;
        }
     }
     return -1;
}

public int linear (List<E> contents, E query)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < contents.size(); ++index)
    {
        if (query.equals(contents.get(index)))
        {
            return index;
        }
     }
     return -1;
}
}
```

Comment: what would the benefits of using a list be?

Comment: You can use all the goodies that come with the Collections API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: One last thing, I hope this is not annoying or a burden to you. But if using Object works as well, what advantage do generics provide?

Comment: these don't need to be instance methods, since the instance is not used for anything; that just forces people to create a dummy object to use them

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, but with new setup due to updated IDE for JavaSE 1.8

```
public static <E extends Comparable<>> int linear (E[] contents, E query) {
    for (int index = 0; index < contents.length; ++index)
    {
        if (query.equals(contents[index]))
        {
            return index;
        }
     }
     return -1;
}
```

Without:

```
<E extends Comparable<>>
```

you get E cannot be resolved to a type.

In order to use the method you must create the array using

```
Integer[] intArray = {23,45,21,55,234,1,34,90};
```

and NOT

```
int[] intArray = {23,45,21,55,234,1,34,90};
```

Then to invoke the method:

```
System.out.println("Key found at Index: " + linear(intArray, 21));
```

Comment: Ok, I've been going to stackoverflow for a while, I often use the search option to get my questions answered without actually asking the question. But I often see people's questions dubbed duplicates and thus left unanswered, simply trying to avoid that. Seems a double edged sword.